# Use bool array in if statement c++

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

I'm a beginner to programming and Stackoverflow. I'm sorry for my bad formatting and my English. My question is if I can do the thing in the if brackets. Thank you :)

```
for(int i=0;i<A.size();++i)
{
     if(Alphabet[i]==false)
            cout<<A[i];
     else if(Alphabet[i]==true)
     {
         cout<<endl<<A[i];
     }
  }
```

Comment: Your title will not help anyone who's having the same problem find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can compare boolean value to a boolean literal. It is, however,  easier to simply use the `bool` value for the if statement. Doing that would look like this

```
if(!Alphabet[i]) // Originally if(Alphabet[i]==false)
```

and like this

```
else if(Alphabet[i]) // Originally else if(Alphabet[i]==true)
```

You don't even have to test for the second condition. Since it will always execute if the first statement doesn't you can replace it with an `else` statement. This would change your `else if` statement to just an `else`. Like this

```
else
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<A[i];
}
```

Comment: ...and in fact you can remove the second `if` completely.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Alphabet` is an array of `bool`, you're just testing the value of an element of that array. It's perfectly safe -- and it can be done much more simply than what you've written:

```
if (Alphabet[i]) {
    std::cout << A[i] << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << A[i];
}
```

The only values a `bool` can have are `true` and `false`. Explicitly comparing a `bool` value for equality to `true` or `false` is needlessly redundant (and such comparisons can be dangerous in some contexts); just test the value of the value itself. Once you've tested whether it's `true`, there's no need to test again whether it's `false`; just use an `else` clause. If you need to test whether it's `false`, use the `!` (logical "not") operator: `if (! Alphabet[i])`.

Finally, you're printing the value of `A[i]` unconditionally, so that part doesn't need to be inside either the `if` or the `else`:

```
std::cout << A[i];
if (Alphabet[i]) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimize the code as

```
If(Alphabet[I])
```

Or

```
If(!Alphabet[I])
```

Yes you can compare it the way you did,nothing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: C++ is case sensitive